# Is there is way to fixed local notification on Notification Center so it can not be clear in swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am new in swift and I want to fixed notification on notification centre so it can not be removed by slide or clicking on Clear on Notification Center.
I am using this code to fire local notification

```
 let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
 content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello!", arguments: nil)
 content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello_message_body", arguments: nil)
 content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
 content.categoryIdentifier = "notify-test"

 let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
 let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "notify-test", content: content, trigger: trigger)

 let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
 center.add(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

The user can always clear notifications. You can't prevent that.